# Изменение ширины блоков после шаблона opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Привет всем. Есть вопрос по поводу стандартного шаблона в OPENCART.
Сделал вот такой вид в макете. Поделил верхнюю часть страницы на 2 части, на слайдер и блок ВК. Все что снизу теперь ссузилось и стало шириной со слайдер. Как растянуть область ниже слайдера на всю ширину?

Залез в home.tpl, там нет html, только php.

```
<?php echo $header; ?> 
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?> 
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?> 
<?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?> 
<?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?> 
<?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?> 
<?php } else { ?> 
<?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?> 
<?php } ?> 
<div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?><?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div> 
<?php echo $column_right; ?></div> 
</div> 
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

[image: Расположение макета в админке]

[image: Нужно растянуть блоки, которые ниже шаблона на всю ширину]

Comment: Насколько я помню, в стандартном шаблоне сайдбар жестко заверстан, тут только если блок этот засунуть в `content_bottom` или в подвал

Comment: Тогда может быть можно уменьшить количество блоков снизу до 3? Я имею ввиду товаров. При сужении они стали очень узкими и было было бы правильным вместо 4 узких сделать 3 нормального размера. В настройках такого нет, в файле тоже я не нашел где меняется количество колонок, колы не помогают.